# How does Objective-C handle subclasses and superclasses with the same property name?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios8

In iOS 8 `NSManagedObject` was given a new property:

`@property (nonatomic, getter=isDeleted, readonly) BOOL deleted;`

Unfortunately, I have already been using a property of the same name in my subclasses of `NSManagedObject` to mark objects as soft deleted.

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *deleted;  // BOOL in CoreData model`

This results in a ton of compiler warnings:

`'getter' attribute on property 'deleted' does not match the property inherited from 'NSManagedObject'`

How does Objective-C handle a superclass and subclass having the same property? I obviously plan on renaming this property across the board but there is already multiple versions of this app in the wild and I am curious of the implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@property` accessors are just regular methods, so they're handled exactly the same way as other methods. In this case, I believe you luck out because the framework (`NSManagedObject`) getter is `-isDeleted` rather than `-deleted`. Since your subclass implements `-deleted`, there's technically no conflict with the getter.

Now, the real issue will be, if `NSManagedObject` internally implements the corresponding `-setDeleted:` setter, your subclasses implementation of that method will be called instead of `NSManagedObject`'s implementation. A quick check using `-instancesRespondToSelector:` seems to reveal that `NSManagedObject` does not actually implement `-setDeleted:` (on OS X, anyway). So, you might be OK.

The actual implications of a conflict like this for your app (assuming a case where you weren't lucky as described above) are not clear to me, not knowing exactly what your app is doing or why. For what it's worth, the `-isDeleted` method on NSManagedObject is not at all new. It was simply promoted to a declared `@property` in iOS 8 (presumably to ease Swift interoperability). It was probably always a bad idea to have your own `deleted` property...